# How do I download all photos to a HDD from iCloud?

Tags: icloud, photos, data-transfer, data

I have a very simple request, I want to download all my data, or at least all my photos, from iCloud to a local drive, and then I can do whatever I want with them.

The instructions here:

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201302

don't work - unless I am missing something. When I choose Import, I see all pictures all through, and I just want to download from Photos those that are on the cloud.

For Google, it is very easy, you just go to Google checkout, and get a ZIP file with all YOUR data. How can the same be done with Apple ID?

Comment: Hey kloop, Welcome to Apple.SE! iCloud is just a storage and sync for all the photos in photos.app. The import you're talking about is for new photos to bring into the photo library.

Comment: thanks. but how do I download all the data from the cloud to a different local folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to https://privacy.apple.com/account , sign-in and request download for photos.

Another method can be to allow *Download originals to Mac* in Photos app preferences and then go to `/Users/yourname/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary/Masters` after all the photos are downloaded.

> You can request a copy of the data that Apple stores which is
>   associated with your Apple ID. This information includes, but is not
>   limited to:
>
> - Your Apple ID account details and sign-in records.
> - Data that you store with iCloud such as contacts, calendars, notes,
>     bookmarks, reminders, email, photos, videos, and document.

<sup>from https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT208502</sup>