# Import a bazillion photos from iCloud to mac

Tags: iphone, mac, icloud, photos

I am very, **very** desperate and annoyed at this moment, being the family IT-Guy over long distance, having nothing but remote access to a mac with an iPhone, that is not in any way connected over any account to this Mac.

I have imported all locally stored photos from this iPhone to the Mac, but now I have around 4.000 photos on the iCloud account of this smartphone, that need to be imported today to this Mac.

Problem:
I am accessing the iCloud photos over the browser, seeing all 4.000 photos, but can only import 1.000 at once. But I cannot, for the life of me pick more than 40-50 photos at once, because the browser won't scroll up, when moving the mouse to the upper edge while selecting. If someone please has a smart solution to this mess I would be extremely thankful!

**Please**

Thanks for reading.

In regard of the comment claiming this to be a duplicate of another question:
It's true, they are similar and the presented solution under the other question is awesome, but I need a solution that works today and not within the next 7 days, as it is mentioned by the service provided by apple.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I download all photos to a HDD from iCloud?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/363974/how-do-i-download-all-photos-to-a-hdd-from-icloud)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but sadly this won't work here, due to the waiting time on the apple service and because the iPhone does not share the same Apple ID account as the Mac.

Comment: Requiring a solution "today" would depend on where in the world you are. For some of us, today is nearly over, for others, just beginning. Putting a time-constraint on a question really doesn't work for stack exchange, as it isn't a real-time resource.

Comment: You are most certainly right at that point, it was not my intention to be rude. If nobody can provide a solution within the next couple hours, that works without a long waiting time, then it'll work fine, if not, then not.

Comment: @Deven regarding your top first comment, I don't think same Apple ID is required. You have to sign-in whatever the device maybe. You'll be notified via iPhone's Apple ID.

Answer (score 1):

Select a photo, go to another, far away photo, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and select another. It should download more photos at a time.

This is not a comprehensive solution to such a situation. Just because questioner can select 40-50 photos in browser, I am suggesting a way to select more.

I recommend Firefox for such download. It comes from experience of [Firefox Send](https://send.firefox.com). Safari gets stuck in bigger downloads.